# Remove object fields by updating the complete object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is some data which is stored in a mongoDB document:

```
{ 
    _id: "123"
    order: 1
    parent: "Dueqmd64nTxM3u9Cm"
    type: "article"
    unit: "kg"
}
```

While all the saved data will be calculated and validated first (that's why I don't use only `data = { order: 2 }`), I'm using the complete object to update the document:

```
var data = { 
    order: 2
    parent: "Dueqmd64nTxM3u9Cm"
    type: "article"
    unit: "kg"
}

Collection.update(
    { _id: 123 }, 
    { $set: data }
);
```

This is working.

But if I want to remove some values, it doesn't work:

```
var data = { 
    order: 2
    parent: "Dueqmd64nTxM3u9Cm"
    type: "article"
    unit: undefined
}

Collection.update(
    { _id: 123 }, 
    { $set: data }
);
```

I'm expecting the `unit`-field to get removed. But that isn't the case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove fields, use the **[`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)** operator:

```
data = {
    unit: ""
};
Collection.update(
    { _id: 123 }, 
    { $set: data }
);
```